# How can I remove all instances of a specific text-phrase?

Tags: javascript, dom

In a situation that the body area of a webpage is the only accessible part, is there a way to remove all instances of a particular text-phrase (written in HTML) using inline JavaScript or another inline capable language?

This could be useful in many situations, such as people using a Tiny.cc/customurl and wanting to remove the portion stating "tiny.cc/"

---

If specifics are allowed, we're modifying a calendar plugin using Tiny.cc to create a custom URLs (tiny.cc/customurl). The plugin shows the full URL by default so we'd like to strip the text "tiny.cc/" and keep the "customurl" portion in our code:

```
<div class="ews_cal_grid_custom_item_3">
  <div class="ews_cal_grid_select_checkbox_clear" id="wGridTagChk" onclick="__doPostBack('wGridTagChk', 'tiny.cc/Baseball-JV');" >&nbsp;</div>
                            tiny.cc/Baseball-JV
  </div>
```

The part we'd like to remove is the `http://tiny.cc/` on the 3rd line by itself.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without replacing all the HTML (which wrecks all event handlers) and to do it without recursion (which is generally faster), you can do this:

```
function removeText(top, txt) {
    var node = top.firstChild, index;
    while(node && node != top) {
        // if text node, check for our text
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            // without using regular expressions (to avoid escaping regex chars),
            // replace all copies of this text in this text node
            while ((index = node.nodeValue.indexOf(txt)) != -1) {
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substr(0, index) + node.nodeValue.substr(index + txt.length);
            }
        }
        if (node.firstChild) {
            // if it has a child node, traverse down into children
            node = node.firstChild;
        } else if (node.nextSibling) {
            // if it has a sibling, go to the next sibling
            node = node.nextSibling;
        } else {
            // go up the parent chain until we find a parent that has a nextSibling
            // so we can keep going
            while ((node = node.parentNode) != top) {
                if (node.nextSibling) {
                    node = node.nextSibling;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2y9eH/

To do this on the entire document, you would just call:

```
removeText(document.body, "http://tiny.cc/Baseball-JV");
```

Comment: Nice one on the recursion-less tree walk.  I'm not convinced the speed  difference is worth the readability, but I like the design.

Comment: @cloudfeet - it depends upon how long and deep the document is and how much the speed matters.  Note: this is also a generic function that works with any text string even one that has regex chars in it.  But, it does take more code to do it without recursion.

Comment: Is this function portion able to run inline? I can't modify the head to include an external js file.

Comment: @beta208 - yes it can be inline.  You must wait until the DOM is finished loading before running it.  The simplest way to do that would be `window.onload = function() {removeText(document.body, "http://tiny.cc/Baseball-JV");};` or if other code is using `onload`, then use an event listener.   In fact, it is inline (at the end of the `<body>` section) in the jsFiddle I linked.

Comment: @jfriend00 - you're right, doing it recursively is a bit slower (at least in my browser), according to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fHE8/1/) based on both our answers.  Personally, I wouldn't worry about it - if speed is an issue, and your document is really that long, then I'd look at other optimisations first, like whether you need to be filtering the whole document or not.

Comment: @cloudfeet - with a larger document where the differences would show more, it looks like the non-recursive version is `2x` (Chrome) to `5x` (Safari) to `9x` (IE) faster.  I agree it would be useful to limit the search to only targeted portions of the document if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can supply the data in string format, you can use Regular Expressions to do this for you.

You could parse the *whole* innerHTML of the body tag, if that is all that you can access. This is a slow and kinda-bad-practice method, but for explanation's sake:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /http:\/\/tiny\.cc\//i,    // The regular expression to search for
    "");                       // Waht to replace with (nothing).
```

The whole expression is contained within forward slashes, so any forward slashes inside the regexp need to be escaped with a backslash.

This goes for other characters that have special meaning in regexp, such as the period. A single period (`.`) denotes matching 'any' character. To match a period, it must be escaped (`\.`)

EDIT:

If you wish to keep the reference to the URL in the onclick, you can modify the regexp to not match when inside single quotes (as your example):

```
/([^']http:\/\/tiny\.cc\/[^'])/i
```

Comment: This is a great start, but I need to keep the onclick="__doPostBack('..., 'http://tiny.cc/Baseball-JV');" instance of tiny.cc as it provides the link.

Comment: @beta208 you will find that this will in fact replace all instances of the regexp across the whole of the body's HTML.

Comment: How can I just remove it within the plain text of the div, but not the onClick property of the div?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace all the instances of that string in the HTML, then you'll have to recursively iterate over the node structure, for instance:

```
function textFilter(element, search, replacement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = element.childNodes[i];
        var nodeType = child.nodeType;
        if (nodeType == 1) { // element
            textFilter(child, search, replacement);
        } else if (nodeType == 3) { // text node
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(search, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just grab hold of the appropriate element, and call this function on it:

```
var el = document.getElementById('target');
textFilter(el, /http:\/\/tiny.cc\//g, "");​  // You could use a regex
textFilter(el, "Baseball", "Basketball");​   //  or just a simple string
```

Comment: Hey great, I'll try this out and see if I can get this working as inline JS.

Comment: For my clarity sake, what is the g in the regex textFilter?

Comment: It's the "global" modifier.  If you omit it, then it only replaces one instance per text node: http://jsfiddle.net/DnVEa/4/

Comment: Oh, nice thank you. Is this function portion able to run inline? I can't modify the head to include an external js file.

Comment: I don't see why not.  You could either run it using body.onload, like `<body onload="runTextFilter();">`, or you could place it at the bottom of the document, after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: When calling textFilter recursively, I think the second argument is supposed to be `search`, not `regex`.